# how to update table with subquery in where clause

Tags: mysql, subquery, sql-update

i have a main table `categories` like this

```
categories_id | categories_status | parent_id
     1                  1               0
     2                  1               0
     3                  1               1
     4                  1               2
     5                  1               1
     6                  1               2
```

and a reference table `products_to_categories`

```
categories_id | products_id
      3             778
      3             998
      5             666
      5             744
```

I select all the categories with no child-category:

```
SELECT * FROM categories
WHERE categories_id not in ( SELECT parent_id FROM categories )
# gets entries with id 3, 4, 5, 6
```

and no products in reference table:

```
AND categories_id NOT IN ( SELECT categories_id FROM products_to_categories )
# gets entries with id 4, 6
```

Now i would like to update the categories_status for this result but it don't work just changing SELECT to UPDATE:

```
UPDATE categories
SET categories_status = 0
WHERE categories_id not in ( SELECT parent_id FROM categories )
AND categories_id NOT IN ( SELECT categories_id FROM products_to_categories )
```

There a few similar questions, but i can't figure out how to change my example...

Thanks & best regards,

Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of sub-queries, use a left outer join

```
update 
categories c1
left outer join categories c2 on c1.ID = c2.Parent_id
left outer join products_to_categories p on c1.categories_id = p.categories_id
set c1.categories_status = 0
where c2.ID is null and p.categories_id is null
```

Comment: I hate it, when people make it look so easy. it makes me look stupid ;) but this is it, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot update records contained in subquery where conditions.
Try to use direct conditions like:

```
// this rely that all categories_id higher than 0 should be valid relations
WHERE categories_id < 1
```

..this should work, but i would like to give you advice related to performance - use NULL values in case of records without parents.
Than the condition should be `WHERE categories_id IS NULL`

Answer (score 0):

I have a problem with a update:

```
 UPDATE [base].[dbo].[test] SET Idstatement = 20    
 WHERE Iddoc IN 
             (SELECT [Iddoc] FROM [base].[dbo].[test] 
              WHERE Document = 'INV' AND Idstatement = 50 AND Year = '2017'
             )
```

Subquery returned more than 1 value.

This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
The statement has been terminated.